# Azure Data Factory: 'Get Metadata' Activity Retrieving the Incorrect Column Count

Tags: azure-data-factory, metadata

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOX7P.png)

Hi, I'm currently running into an issue whereby the 'Get Metadata' activity is retrieving an incorrect column count from a desired table (table stored in a relational SQL Database). It's outputting a column count of 8 when the column count should be 37.

I've inputted another table from the same database with 20 columns and again the 'Get Metadata' activity outputs a column count of 8...

Has anybody come across this before or know why this might be?

Cheers in advance

Comment: Hi Luig, Sometimes, metadata information may not be up-to-date. click the "Refresh" button in the 'Get Metadata' activity to update the schema.

Comment: Hi @LuiG, if you're trying to access a SQL table's data, then you need to use Lookup activity not Get Metadata activity. Lookup is used to fetch data from datasets, whereas Get Metadata is used for fetching metadata of files or directories of datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Get Meta data activity is giving proper result for me.

[image]

I suggest you publish and retry the same.

If still it's not working, use the lookup activity as workaround for it.

Use the below query in lookup query option to get the column count of the table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = '<your schema name>'
  AND table_name = '<your table name>';
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Use the below expression later on after the lookup activity to get the column count.

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.count
```

Answer (score 0):

It may do due below reasons. Kindly cross check once.

- Open your dataset and go to schema tab and see how many columns its showing there. Clear the schema and reimport schema and then re-run it.
- You can also use `lookup activity` with query option and write query to get column counts.